# Indices of intersection of lists

Tags: python, list

Given two lists of equal length:

```
_list = [1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15, 5, 0, 6]
_list2 = [7, 4, 0, 1, 5, 5, 7, 2, 2]
```

How do I try getting an output like this:

`output = [(0,3), (1,1), (3,0), (6,4), (6,5), (7,2)]`

Here the intersection of two lists are obtained and the common elements' indices are arranged in the list:

`output = list of (index of an element in _list, where it appears in _list2)`

Trying intersection with sets is not an option since the set removes the repeating elements.

Comment: Did the elements in your two lists are unique ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus not in the sample input

Comment: Isn't `(1,1)` missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the output should be `[(0,3), (2,2), (3,0), (6,4), (6,5), (7,2)]` ? And if there is duplicates, which index should you use ?

Comment: Sorry, that (2,2) should have been (1,1). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ChihebNexus both indices should be used for duplicates in both lists. Sorry I couldn't make it clearer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Basic-Intermediate*: As a generator:

```
def find_matching_indices(a, b):
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(b):
            if x == y:
                yield i, j

list(find_matching_indices(list1_, list2_))
# [(0, 3), (1, 1), (3, 0), (3, 6), (6, 4), (6, 5), (7, 2)]
```

*Basic-Intermediate*: As a list comprehension:

```
[(i, j)  for i, x in enumerate(list1_) for j, y in enumerate(list2_) if x == y]
# [(0, 3), (1, 1), (3, 0), (3, 6), (6, 4), (6, 5), (7, 2)]
```

These solutions involve two loops.

---

*Intermediate-Advanced*: For fun, a dictionary is another data structure you might consider:

```
import collections as ct

import more_itertools as mit


def locate_indices(a, b):
    """Return a dictionary of `a` index keys found at `b` indices."""
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    for i, y in enumerate(a):
        idxs = list(mit.locate(b, lambda z: z == y))
        if idxs: dd[i].extend(idxs)
    return dd


locate_indices(list1_, list2_)
# defaultdict(list, {0: [3], 1: [1], 3: [0, 6], 6: [4, 5], 7: [2]})
```

Note the index of list `a` is the key in the dictionary.  All indices in list `b` that share the same value are appended.

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) was used since it is helpful in building dictionaries with list values.  See more on the [third-party tool `more_itertools.locate()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate), which simply yields all indices that satisfy the lambda condition - an item in list `a` is also found in `b`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict


def mathcing_indices(*lists):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: tuple([] for _ in range(len(lists))))
    for l_idx, l in enumerate(lists):
        for i, elem in enumerate(l):
            d[elem][l_idx].append(i)
  return sorted([tup for _, v in d.items() for tup in product(*v)])
```

This solution builds a dictionary that tracks the indices that values appear at in the input lists.  So if the value `5` appears at indices 0 and 2 of the first list and index 3 of the second, the value for `5` in the dictionary would be `([0, 2], [3])`

It then uses `itertools.product` to build all the combinations of those indices.

This looks more complicated than the other answers here, but because it is `O(nlogn)` and not `O(n**2)` it is [significantly faster](https://repl.it/@Haugh/BackPassionateMaltesedog), especially for large inputs. Two length 1000 lists of random numbers 0-1000 complete 100 tests in ~.4 seconds using the above algorithm and 6-13 seconds using some of the others here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that runs in `O(n log n)`:

```
﻿﻿﻿ind1 = numpy.argsort(_list)
ind2 = numpy.argsort(_list2)
pairs = []
i = 0
j = 0
while i<ind1.size and j<ind2.size:
    e1 = _list[ind1[i]]
    e2 = _list2[ind2[j]]
    if e1==e2:
        pairs.append((ind1[i],ind2[j]))
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    elif e1<e2:
        i = i +1
    elif e2<e1:
        j = j + 1
print(pairs)
```